# make slideshow background resize with browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, slideshow

I want the images in my slideshow that serves as the background for my website to resize as the browser does. Below is the code I have which doesn't seem to change anything just yet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pager: '#smallnav',
    pause: 1,
    speed: 1800,
    timeout: 8500
  });
});
```

```css
#slideshow,
img.bgM {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="images/back/1.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/2.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/3.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/4.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/5.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/6.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/7.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/8.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/9.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/10.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/11.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/12.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/13.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="images/back/14.JPG" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
</div>
```

Comment: its not working maybe because of the style by the plugin.. did you try using 

`width: 100% !important;`

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2tqp54sb/9/)
The Plugin you are using is giving width and height in `px` more to that its setting them as inline style which has a highest priority to overcome this you can use `!important` if there no way but if you give `max width` and `max-height` you won't require `!important`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pager: '#smallnav',
    pause: 1,
    speed: 800,
    timeout: 500
  });
});
```

```css
#slideshow,
.bgM {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle/3.0.3/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://spicyip.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/open-source-software-1.jpg" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
  <img src="http://www.rapidsoftsystems.com/img/nimages/opensource.gif" alt="image1" class="bgM" />
</div>
```

**Please Note:**

 if you use plugin like slider you used here please make working demo so volunteer can easily tell you where you make mistake
FYI: if you use jQuery plugin [CDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/) you can find each jQuery library in this which will be helpful

Comment: thanks. that works now but there's another problem. all the floating divs I had on the page have disappeared. how do I get them back?

Comment: oh never mind. Im using the original plugin and used width: 100% !important. thanks.